# Group Multi-Dimensional Array and Reassign Keys

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting this from my select statement:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-06 09:15:00
        [type] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-06 11:00:00
        [type] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-06 11:15:00
        [type] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-06 13:00:00
        [type] => 4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-06 13:29:00
        [type] => 5
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-06 15:00:00
        [type] => 6
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-06 15:15:00
        [type] => 7
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-06 17:00:00
        [type] => 8
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-07 09:00:00
        [type] => 1
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-07 10:15:00
        [type] => 2
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-07 10:30:00
        [type] => 3
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-07 13:00:00
        [type] => 4
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-07 13:30:00
        [type] => 5
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-07 14:30:00
        [type] => 6
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-07 14:45:00
        [type] => 7
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2013-11-07 17:00:00
        [type] => 8
    )

)
```

What I want to do is group the arrays by date and set each time value as an element of that array, but change the key from [time] to the number value assigned to [type].

So I'd get something like this:

```
$records[] = array();

$records[2013-11-06] => Array
    ( [1] => 09:15:00
      [2] => 11:15:00 
      [3] => 11:15:00 
      etc.
    )
$records[2013-11-07] => Array
    ( [1] => 09:00:00
      [2] => 10:15:00 
      [3] => 10:30:00
      etc.
    )
```

Any help is GREALY appreciated, as I am STUCK!  Thank you!

Comment: Please, tell which database management system (DBMS) you are using. Sometimes you can solve the problem rewriting the query. :)

Comment: it's simple. Just try.

Comment: You should include any attempts you have tried (and failed) with as well

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using MySQL, you can just rewrite your query like this:

```
  SELECT DATE(time) AS date, GROUP_CONCAT(TIME(time) ORDER BY time) AS time
    FROM table_name
GROUP BY date
```

And you'll get your data like that:

```
|------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| date       | time                                                                    |
|------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2013-11-06 | 09:15:00,11:00:00,11:15:00,13:00:00,13:29:00,15:00:00,15:15:00,17:00:00 |
| 2013-11-07 | 09:00:00,10:15:00,10:30:00,13:00:00,13:30:00,14:30:00,14:45:00,17:00:00 |
|------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

From that you can simply use PHP [explode()](http://www.php.net/explode) function to get all time values of each record as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$records = array();
foreach($yourarray as $arr)
  {
  list($date,$time)=explode(' ',$arr['time']);
  $records[$date][$arr['type']]=$time;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over your rows and assign the needed values.

```
$records = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($row['time']);
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
    $time = date("H:i:s", $timestamp);
    if (!is_array($records[$date])) $records[$date] = array();
    $records[$date][ $row['type'] ] = $time;
}
```